Expo iOS app crashing immediately on open w/ react-native-google-mobile-ads
I'm experiencing an issue where my Expo React Native app is crashing immediately on start after installing the react-native-google-mobile-ads package.
UPDATED:
I've taken the following steps so far...

Install using npx expo install react-native-google-mobile-ads
Update app.json per the documentation (obscured my IDs):

"plugins": [
      "expo-router",
      "expo-localization",
      "expo-apple-authentication",
      [
        "react-native-google-mobile-ads",
        {
          "androidAppId": "ca-app-pub-<id obscured>",
          "iosAppId": "ca-app-pub-<id obscured>"
        }
      ]
    ],


Create a development build
Install development build on device

Curious if I'm still doing something incorrectly here. Any help is appreciated!


It should be app.config.js not app.config.json
There is no need to have both app.config.js and app.json.  Both files can exist but ultimately their purpose is to return a JS object describing the configuration of your Expo app.  Personally I use app.config.js because it allows me to dynamically calculate some of the Expo properties based on the build environment.

export default ({config}) => {
  let appConfig;

  if (process?.env?.EAS_BUILD === 'true') {

    // We're in the EAS_BUILD container.
    appConfig = require('./src/build/current-config/app.json');

  } else if (process?.env?.COMMON_EXPO_PATH) {

    // we're running in a local dev environment
    appConfig = {
      APP_DISPLAY_NAME: process.env?.APP_DISPLAY_NAME,
      APP_INTERNAL_NAME: process.env?.APP_INTERNAL_NAME,
      DEEP_LINK_SCHEME: process.env?.DEEP_LINK_SCHEME,
      FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID: process.env?.FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
      GOOGLE_MAPS_KEY_ANDROID: process.env?.GOOGLE_MAPS_KEY_ANDROID,
      GOOGLE_MAPS_KEY_IOS: process.env?.GOOGLE_MAPS_KEY_IOS,
      LABEL_CLAZZ_ACT: process.env?.LABEL_CLAZZ_ACT,
      LABEL_CLAZZ_ACTS: process.env?.LABEL_CLAZZ_ACTS,
      PROJ_SHORT_NAME: process.env?.PROJ_SHORT_NAME,
      SENTRY_ORG: process.env?.SENTRY_ORG,
      SENTRY_PROJECT: process.env?.SENTRY_PROJECT,
      SPLASH_BACKGROUND_COLOR: process.env?.SPLASH_BACKGROUND_COLOR,
      EAS_PROJECT_ID: process.env?.EAS_PROJECT_ID,
    };
  }
  
  const expoConfig = calculateExpoConfigSettings(appConfig);

  // return the app configuration (instead of `app.json`):
  return {...config, ...expoConfig};
};


The settings you show for your app.json are for the React-Native configuration (that involves other steps).  But since you are using Expo I would encourage you to look at the Expo configuration steps:



After referring to the docs per your recommendation, I re-installed using npx expo install and followed the above app.json instructions. However, the new build is still crashing.

Then you will want to get the "system logs" from the device (or emulator/simulator) to determine what the specific stack trace is for the crash.  That will help you narrow down the cause of the crash.  https://docs.expo.dev/workflow/logging/
